# PyDev Eclipse Plugin fails to update in Eclipse Update Manager

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm trying to update some software in Eclipse, and mostly haven't had problems, but when I try to update PyDev (Python plugin) I get this error:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2219600778088128210.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2219600778088128210.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.analysis,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6795154829597372736.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6795154829597372736.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.codecompletion,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile855072635271316145.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile855072635271316145.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.debug,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4688521627100670190.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4688521627100670190.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.fastparser,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1084399815407097736.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1084399815407097736.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.refactoring,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4184776883512095240.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4184776883512095240.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4524222642627962811.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4524222642627962811.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.ast,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile3249163288841740294.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile3249163288841740294.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.core,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1814921458326062966.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1814921458326062966.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.customizations,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4652077908204425024.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4652077908204425024.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.debug,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5865734778550017815.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5865734778550017815.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.django,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1400608644382694448.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1400608644382694448.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.help,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5475958427511010644.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5475958427511010644.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.jython,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile269530960804801404.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile269530960804801404.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.parser,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6988087748918334886.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6988087748918334886.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.refactoring,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1524645906700502816.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1524645906700502816.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_core,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile7684330420892093099.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile7684330420892093099.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6948600865186203811.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6948600865186203811.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_ui,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2509877364480980768.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2509877364480980768.jar
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.python.pydev.feature,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile7424055901779492006.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile7424055901779492006.jar

I run Eclipse as an administrator and I don't understand what could cause this issue.

Regards,

Comment: I've fixed the issue by updating Eclipse from 3.7 to 4.3 - update succeeds now without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the best resolution for this is to update from Eclipse 3.7 to 4.3+.